# convert a string to yyyy/mm/dd datetime type

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I tried to convert a string into datetime object with yyyy/mm/dd format. using striptime() function it returns yyyy-mm-dd format with datetime.date type. I have used strftime() to convert into yyyy/mm/dd format but it returns a string type. How can we get a datetime type object with yyyy/mm/dd format?

```py
datestr = '25/03/2019'
date_obj = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
print(date_obj)
date_formatted = date_obj.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
print(type(datestr))
print(type(date_formatted))
```

Comment: datetime objects don't have formats, you can get a string representation of your datetime in a variety of formats using `strftime` as in your attempt above. What, besides print, are you trying to do with the datetime object after creating it?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help,

```
import datetime

date_time_str = '2018-06-29 08:15:27.243860'  
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print('Date:', date_time_obj.date())  
print('Time:', date_time_obj.time())  
print('Date-time:', date_time_obj)
```

Also recommend you to read [this article](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/).